# How to use react-native-vision-camera Frame Processor to detect human face?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-mlkit

How to use react-native-vision-camera Frame Processor to detect human faces? I tried using a package called vision-camera-face-detector but it fails my built when I am trying to create my react native cli app apk is there any other solution to detect human faces using react-native-vision-camera Frame Processor?

```
export default function App() {
  const [cameraPermission, setCameraPermission] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const cameraPermissionStatus = await Camera.requestCameraPermission();
      setCameraPermission(cameraPermissionStatus);
    })();
  }, []);

  console.log(`Camera permission status: ${cameraPermission}`);

  const devices = useCameraDevices();
  const cameraDevice = devices.back;

  const renderDetectorContent = () => {
    if (cameraDevice && cameraPermission === 'authorized') {
      return (
        <Camera
          style={styles.camera}
          device={cameraDevice}
          isActive={true}
        />
      );
    }
    return <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#1C6758" />;
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.saveArea}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
          <Text style={styles.headerText}>React Native Face Detector</Text>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>

    
      {renderDetectorContent()}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I can use the vision-camera-face-detector plugin to detect face.

See the docs https://github.com/rodgomesc/vision-camera-face-detector

Here's example the frame processor:

```
  const frameProcessor = useFrameProcessor((frame) => {
    'worklet';
    const scannedFaces = scanFaces(frame);
    runOnJS(setFaces)(scannedFaces);
  }, []);
```